How signature will be generate where payload and query parameter in present in API
How signature will be generate where payload and query parameter in present in API?
Some of API dose not have nonce and signature validation due to api dose not have query parameter and payload, we want to make those api secure.
We are expecting some random number generate and validate on server such that the API is coming secure source and no MIMT happen or rate play.
